# Отложеный рестарт в Adobe Animate cc HTML5 Canvas

Tags: animate, adobe, html5-canvas

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли, и если да, то как, в Adobe Animate cc HTML5 Canvas сделать, чтобы страница сама перезагружалась каждые 10 мин.

Answer (score 0):

Автоматическое обновление страницы браузера на HTML

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="15" /> <!--Рестарт страницы каждые 15 сек -->
----
<\head>
```

https://bloggood.ru/vebmasteru/avtomaticheskoe-obnovlenie-stranicy-brauzera-na-html-php-i-javascript.html/